# How convert file. a to .c or other extension? I need read file .a

Tags: c, windows

Good day, I am working with Codeblock IDE under Windows in C language and I got the static library in file ".a" with the development of some functions. I must see somehow the code of the functions in the file because i need.
I was reading a lot on the forum but I could not solve my doubt.

someone could help? Tanks!!

Comment: `*.a` files are compiled libraries. You can't see the source code unless you decompile (which is very hard or impossible).

Comment: What library is this? If it's an open-source one, you can find the code online.

Comment: @Jashaszun I think that your comment should be an answer

Comment: @HotLicks The library does not necessarily have to do with the Code::Blocks IDE. The asker states that he/she is only *using* this IDE.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with `[java]`

Answer (score 4):

(People said that this should be an answer, so here it is!)

`*.a` files are compiled libraries on Windows (the file extension is different on different operating systems). You can't see the source code unless you decompile it (which is very hard or impossible).

(From another comment) However, if the library is from an open-source project, then you might be able to find the source code.

Comment: And what will decompile use??

Comment: @user3284962 [This](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/83838-library-conversion-static-lib-function.html) thread might be useful.